# Allow access to a subdomain only when redirected from another subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

Lets say we have 2 subdomains:

sub1.domain1.com and sub2.domain2.com.

First sub1 is getting redirected (through CPANEL) to sub2.
Can I deny access to anyone who tries to access sub2 directly and allow ONLY through the redirection ?

PS domain1 and domain2 are in different VPS servers if that helps..